# Call function from another file

Tags: go

Inside my directory `/go/src/lodo` I have two files, main.go and uniqueElement.

uniqueElement.go

```
package main

import "fmt"

func unique(a []int) {
    var value int

    for i:= range a {
        value = value ^ a[i]

    }
    fmt.Println(value)

}
```

main.go

```
package main

func main() {
    var a = []int{1, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2}


    unique(a[0:])
}
```

I get an error

```
./main.go:7: undefined: unique
```

How can I correctly call unique from `main`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probably ran your code with `go run main.go` that only compiles and runs `main.go` try running `go run main.go uniqueElement.go` or building and running the binary generated

Comment: Or, even better: `go run *.go` to include all

Comment: True, unless you have other go files with conflicting function names, typically, another file with a `main()` function

Answer (score 1):

Change the name from `unique` to `Unique`.

Comment: The files are in the same package, so he is able to access unexported functions

Answer (score 1):

The following codes work for me:

```
//module github.com/go-restful/article

package article

func IndexPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}
```

> This func must be Exported, **Capitalized**, and Comment added

The use in main.go

```
//module github.com/go-restful

package main

import (article "github.com/go-restful/article")

func handleRequests() {
    myRouter := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/", article.IndexPage)
}
```